# Proving thermodynamical relation using Gibbs-Duhem relation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I'm given the identity
$$\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial V}\right)_{T, \mu} = \frac{N}{V}.$$

In my textbook I'm given a hint that "Gibbs-Duhem relation might be helpful". Having $dG = d(\mu N)$ and $dG = -SdT + Vdp + \mu dN$ I can write it as $dp = \frac{N}{V}d\mu + \frac{S}{V}dT$, hence $\frac{N}{V} = \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \mu}\right)_{T}$. How can I proceed from there?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already used this substitution to arrive at your first (correct) result:
$$dG = N d\mu + \mu dN = -S dT + V dp + \mu dN$$
$$N d\mu = -S dT + V dp$$

Now instead of solving for $\frac{N}{V}$, solve for $N$:

$$N = -S \left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial \mu}  \right)_p + 
V \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial \mu} \right)_T$$

So then:

$$\left( \frac{\partial N}{\partial V} \right)_{T,\mu} =  
\left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial \mu} \right)_T$$